# How to visualize endpoint test results individually when load testing with k6, influxDB, and Grafana?

Tags: performance, grafana, load-testing, influxdb, k6

I currently have a working version of a load testing environment, using k6, influxDB, and Grafana. Right now, it records requests to a number of endpoints and sends the output to a Grafana dashboard, which aggregates the results and gives me average, min, max, etc. values across **all** the requests.

I'm trying to figure out how to view those statistics on each endpoint individually. I already have the k6 results outputted to individual files for each endpoint. But they are always aggregated in Grafana.

### My k6 script:

```
import http from 'k6/http';
import { sleep } from 'k6';

const config = JSON.parse(open("./"+__ENV.CONFIG_PATH+".json"));
const body = open("./"+__ENV.BODY_PATH+".json");

export const options = {
    stages: [
        { duration: '10s', target: 100 },
        { duration: '15s', target: 10 },
        { duration: '5s', target: 0 }
    ],
};

export default function () {
    http.request(__ENV.METHOD, [app base URL] + __ENV.API_PATH, body, config);
    sleep(1);
}
```

### The command run for each endpoint being tested. Passing the configs as environment variables.

```
k6 run -e METHOD=POST -e API_PATH="..." -e BODY_PATH="..." -e CONFIG_PATH="..." --out influxdb=http://localhost:8086/k6 load.js > [results filename]
```

### An example of a results txt file (for a single endpoint)

```
          /\      |‾‾| /‾‾/   /‾‾/   
     /\  /  \     |  |/  /   /  /    
    /  \/    \    |     (   /   ‾‾\  
   /          \   |  |\  \ |  (‾)  | 
  / __________ \  |__| \__\ \_____/ .io

  execution: local
     script: load.js
     output: InfluxDBv1 (http://localhost:8086)

  scenarios: (100.00%) 1 scenario, 200 max VUs, 1m0s max duration (incl. graceful stop):
           * default: Up to 200 looping VUs for 30s over 3 stages (gracefulRampDown: 30s, gracefulStop: 30s)


running (0m00.9s), 019/200 VUs, 0 complete and 0 interrupted iterations
default   [   3% ] 019/200 VUs  00.9s/30.0s

running (0m01.9s), 039/200 VUs, 19 complete and 0 interrupted iterations
default   [   6% ] 039/200 VUs  01.9s/30.0s

running (0m02.9s), 059/200 VUs, 56 complete and 0 interrupted iterations
default   [  10% ] 059/200 VUs  02.9s/30.0s

running (0m03.9s), 079/200 VUs, 114 complete and 0 interrupted iterations
default   [  13% ] 079/200 VUs  03.9s/30.0s

running (0m04.9s), 099/200 VUs, 191 complete and 0 interrupted iterations
default   [  16% ] 099/200 VUs  04.9s/30.0s

running (0m05.9s), 119/200 VUs, 287 complete and 0 interrupted iterations
default   [  20% ] 119/200 VUs  05.9s/30.0s

running (0m06.9s), 138/200 VUs, 404 complete and 0 interrupted iterations
default   [  23% ] 138/200 VUs  06.9s/30.0s

running (0m07.9s), 158/200 VUs, 539 complete and 0 interrupted iterations
default   [  26% ] 158/200 VUs  07.9s/30.0s

running (0m08.9s), 178/200 VUs, 695 complete and 0 interrupted iterations
default   [  30% ] 178/200 VUs  08.9s/30.0s

running (0m09.9s), 198/200 VUs, 872 complete and 0 interrupted iterations
default   [  33% ] 198/200 VUs  09.9s/30.0s

running (0m10.9s), 200/200 VUs, 1061 complete and 0 interrupted iterations
default   [  36% ] 200/200 VUs  10.9s/30.0s

running (0m11.9s), 200/200 VUs, 1253 complete and 0 interrupted iterations
default   [  40% ] 200/200 VUs  11.9s/30.0s

running (0m12.9s), 200/200 VUs, 1446 complete and 0 interrupted iterations
default   [  43% ] 200/200 VUs  12.9s/30.0s

running (0m13.9s), 200/200 VUs, 1639 complete and 0 interrupted iterations
default   [  46% ] 200/200 VUs  13.9s/30.0s

running (0m14.9s), 200/200 VUs, 1835 complete and 0 interrupted iterations
default   [  50% ] 200/200 VUs  14.9s/30.0s

running (0m15.9s), 200/200 VUs, 2035 complete and 0 interrupted iterations
default   [  53% ] 200/200 VUs  15.9s/30.0s

running (0m16.9s), 200/200 VUs, 2235 complete and 0 interrupted iterations
default   [  56% ] 200/200 VUs  16.9s/30.0s

running (0m17.9s), 200/200 VUs, 2435 complete and 0 interrupted iterations
default   [  60% ] 200/200 VUs  17.9s/30.0s

running (0m18.9s), 200/200 VUs, 2635 complete and 0 interrupted iterations
default   [  63% ] 200/200 VUs  18.9s/30.0s

running (0m19.9s), 200/200 VUs, 2831 complete and 0 interrupted iterations
default   [  66% ] 200/200 VUs  19.9s/30.0s

running (0m20.9s), 200/200 VUs, 3028 complete and 0 interrupted iterations
default   [  70% ] 200/200 VUs  20.9s/30.0s

running (0m21.9s), 200/200 VUs, 3224 complete and 0 interrupted iterations
default   [  73% ] 200/200 VUs  21.9s/30.0s

running (0m22.9s), 200/200 VUs, 3415 complete and 0 interrupted iterations
default   [  76% ] 200/200 VUs  22.9s/30.0s

running (0m23.9s), 200/200 VUs, 3613 complete and 0 interrupted iterations
default   [  80% ] 200/200 VUs  23.9s/30.0s

running (0m24.9s), 200/200 VUs, 3809 complete and 0 interrupted iterations
default   [  83% ] 200/200 VUs  24.9s/30.0s

running (0m25.9s), 182/200 VUs, 4000 complete and 0 interrupted iterations
default   [  86% ] 182/200 VUs  25.9s/30.0s

running (0m26.9s), 142/200 VUs, 4179 complete and 0 interrupted iterations
default   [  90% ] 142/200 VUs  26.9s/30.0s

running (0m27.9s), 101/200 VUs, 4321 complete and 0 interrupted iterations
default   [  93% ] 101/200 VUs  27.9s/30.0s

running (0m28.9s), 063/200 VUs, 4418 complete and 0 interrupted iterations
default   [  96% ] 063/200 VUs  28.9s/30.0s

running (0m29.9s), 024/200 VUs, 4479 complete and 0 interrupted iterations
default   [ 100% ] 024/200 VUs  29.9s/30.0s

     data_received..................: 7.0 MB 228 kB/s
     data_sent......................: 738 kB 24 kB/s
     http_req_blocked...............: avg=692.22µs min=330ns   med=666ns    max=39.61ms p(90)=965ns    p(95)=1.36µs  
     http_req_connecting............: avg=78.13µs  min=0s      med=0s       max=20.26ms p(90)=0s       p(95)=0s      
     http_req_duration..............: avg=14.92ms  min=8.46ms  med=13.44ms  max=86.66ms p(90)=21.09ms  p(95)=24.97ms 
       { expected_response:true }...: avg=14.92ms  min=8.46ms  med=13.44ms  max=86.66ms p(90)=21.09ms  p(95)=24.97ms 
     http_req_failed................: 0.00%  ✓ 0          ✗ 4503 
     http_req_receiving.............: avg=166.01µs min=29.99µs med=78.51µs  max=32.71ms p(90)=143.23µs p(95)=184.04µs
     http_req_sending...............: avg=134.22µs min=55.7µs  med=114.03µs max=9.02ms  p(90)=187.06µs p(95)=256.66µs
     http_req_tls_handshaking.......: avg=602.32µs min=0s      med=0s       max=35.03ms p(90)=0s       p(95)=0s      
     http_req_waiting...............: avg=14.62ms  min=8.28ms  med=13.23ms  max=63.88ms p(90)=20.74ms  p(95)=24.57ms 
     http_reqs......................: 4503   146.220985/s
     iteration_duration.............: avg=1.02s    min=1.01s   med=1.01s    max=1.1s    p(90)=1.02s    p(95)=1.03s   
     iterations.....................: 4503   146.220985/s
     vus............................: 24     min=19       max=200
     vus_max........................: 200    min=200      max=200


running (0m30.8s), 000/200 VUs, 4503 complete and 0 interrupted iterations
default ✓ [ 100% ] 000/200 VUs  30s
```

### Screenshot of what I'm seeing in Grafana:

[image: Grafana Screenshot]

Comment: You need to group/split your panels by whatever dimension you need, e.g. `url.name`. k6 already tags all metrics automatically (and you can add your own tags). With InfluxQL you can then easily extract the data for your dimensions of interest

Comment: Probably what you want is to create a multi-select variable for `url.name`, adjust queries to show data for only one value, and the enable [repetition of rows](https://grafana.com/blog/2020/06/09/learn-grafana-how-to-automatically-repeat-rows-and-panels-in-dynamic-dashboards/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up stumbling across a solution thanks to the helpful comments by @knittl and @markalex which pointed me in the right direction.

As it was mentioned above in the comments section, k6 tags all metrics with `url.name` (among other things) by default. So the solution was to group by `url`, which is represented with the variable `name` in this community dashboard I found online. I'll post a link to it below for anyone who requires the same solution I did.

```
SELECT count("value"), min("value"), median("value"), max("value"), mean("value"), percentile("value", 95) FROM /^http_req_duration$/ WHERE time >= now() - 24h and time <= now() GROUP BY "name"
```

https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/13719-k6-load-testing-results-by-groups/